# wso2esb vfs receiver for text/plain file, but got binary

Tags: vfs, wso2-esb

/Users/lixiaoguang/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-02-24 at 16.22.13.png[log before smooks][1]

```
<proxy name="LocalVFStextToXML" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
 <log level="full"/>
        <smooks config-key="smooks_test">
            <input type="text"/>
            <output type="xml"/>
        </smooks>
        <log level="full"/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">2</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///home/wso2/fileintxt</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">DELETE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///home/wso2/filebackup</parameter></proxy>
```

I want to got the text/plain with wso2 vfs transport, is there any issue with the code or some configuration I have to check?thanks~

Comment: log as below:'[2018-02-24 16:17:06,625]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:E6FEE29A75C81CE7FA1519460226630, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">MTIz</ns:binary></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'

Comment: Where is your code?